# ARR The request cannot be routed because it has reached the Max-Forwards limit. The server may be self-referencing itself in request routing topology

Tags: arr

I have two Windows 2008 R2 Standard Server on which IIS 7.5 is installed (Server1 and Server2). On Server1 I have installed Web Farm Framework 2.2 and created a server Farm "myFarm.com". I have also installed ARR on the Server1.

In the server farm, I have added Server2 and Server1 as the secondary servers. I have configured the ARR with default option. Load balancing is configured to "Round Robin so that request can go to both of the server randomly.

To test my setup I have created a Test.ASPX page and deployed it in both servers.  This is a simple page which returns serverName on which server page is executed. This way I would know that load balancing is working or not.

Then I opened Internet Exlorer and tried to browse my Test.ASPX page from server1 which hosts Web Farm and ARR. Everytime I hit the page request goes to Server2 only. I made my server2 has unhealthy in the webfarm to check if Server1 handle the request or not. When I tried to hit the Test.aspx in the browser, I was surprised to add following error:

**The request cannot be routed because it has reached the Max-Forwards limit. The server may be self-referencing itself in request routing topology.**

From the error message it appears that when my server2 is not available ARR is sending the request to Server1 which is again sending it to itself causing loopback. I couldn't find a way to stop this loopback.

One of the solution which I found after searching is that I should not add Server1 to the web farm as it is hosting ARR, but I have only two servers and I don't want to use one server just for ARR.

As soon as I mark my server2 healthy request starts getting executed by server2.

Could someone suggest what should be configured to resolve this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can do a self reference ARR and avoid to get the max-fowards limits if you configure ARR on port 80 and your web farm on another port : ex 8080

So when ARR route the request to itself he will do it on another port so avoid to foward and foward again the request.

Enjoy :-)

Comment: Hello, How can I do that step by step? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem recently and this is the configuration that helped me (following what Cedric suggested in another post).

So, here is what you can do:

- In your web-site configuration, add additional binding for Server2, for example, to port 88 (i.e. you should be able to get response by navigating to `http://Server2:88/Test.ASPX`).
- In your server farm configuration, add condition to your routing (Routing Rules -> URL Rewrite) to avoid processing requests that go to port 88:

[image: URL rewrite configuration]